# Cpanel cron run page every 5 minutes

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

My page in not reloading every 5 minutes, Im using this cron:

```
 */5 * * * * curl http://www.mysite.com/index.php
```

Note: I have seen a similar question about this, but it wasnt talking about my specific problem.

Comment: do you have curl installed?

Comment: I dont know.. How can I see it? Is it supose to b installed when someone get a host with cpanel?

Comment: you should be able to run php_info from cpanel and see all the settings for PHP. Search for curl there to see if it is enabled

Answer (score 1):

If your index.php is on the local system than just run it as if it were a script:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/my/site/index.php
```

Comment: But It there any way to use curl, with this: --silent ? which can work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared hosting , they they will not allow you to manually configure **cron** jobs.

You can set 60 crons for same script per hour starting at different minute of hour.